# Date calculation using javaScript

Tags: javascript

I need date algorithms, Which will display me how long I have been given a date anywhere.

Example: 
 Suppose

```
Today is 01/06/2019 (dd/mm/yy)
BirthDate is 31/05/2019 (dd/mm/yy)
```

Now, My age is 1 day 0 Months and 0 years
[NOTE: I need all of them, It means day/month and years]

I have been read at least 23 articles/post in this site but they only give years or month or date but not everything in one...

```
var date, cDate, cMonth, cYears, oDate, oMonth, oYears; 
date = new Date()

//current date
cDate = date.getDate()
cMonth = date.getMonth()
cYears = date.getFullYear()

//birth date 
oDate = 01
oMonth = 05
oYears = 2019
```

(Multiplying is not the main solution I think so, need to work with all arithmetics operator)

Comment: So you want the difference between two dates expressed in _years_, _months_, and _days_?

Comment: Exactly, You are right.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `moment`, so there you can do:

```
var a = moment("04/09/2019 15:00:00");
var b = moment("04/09/2013 14:20:30");

console.log(a.diff(b, 'years'))
console.log(a.diff(b, 'months'))
console.log(a.diff(b, 'days'))
```

Similarly, you can get minutes, hours and seconds if you need.

While using the library [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the result you need

```
var birth = new Date("5/31/2019"); // mm/dd/year
var today = new Date();

var diff = today.valueOf()-birth.valueOf();

var result = new Date(diff);

var dayDiff = result.getDate() - 1; //because epoch start from 1st
var yearDiff = result.getFullYear() - 1970; //because epoch start from 1970

var str = `${dayDiff} day ${result.getMonth()} Months and ${yearDiff} years`;

console.log(str);
```